# FileBeat not sending data to ElasticSearch Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, devops, kibana, filebeat, elk

I'm unable to receive data in the Kibana dashboard from the Filebeat agent. I'm using self-managed ELK with AWS EC2 server. Below is my **filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/ubuntu/logs/consumer-app/*.log

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["http://PUBLIC_IP:9200"]
setup.kibana:
  host: "http://PUBLIC_IP:5601"
```

**elasticsearch.yaml**

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: PUBLIC_IP
http.port: 9200
discovery.type: single-node
```

**kibana.yml**

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: PUBLIC_IP
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://PUBLIC_IP:9200"]
```

When I try to hit **sudo filebeat setup** command. Im getting the below error.

Overwriting ILM policy is disabled. Set `setup.ilm.overwrite: true` for enabling.
Index setup finished.
Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)

Exiting: error connecting to Kibana: fail to get the Kibana version: HTTP GET request to http://localhost:5601/api/status fails: fail to execute the HTTP GET request: Get "http://localhost:5601/api/status": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5601: connect: connection refused. Response: .

Since I'm new to ELK and filebeat, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It should work for multiple servers as well. There should be a tricky problem somewhere. Could you give some details?

Comment: Yeah sure @hkulekci I've added kibana & elasticsearch yml too which I'm using. So, filebeat in the child server sends logs to ElasticSearch built-in server --> visualise through kibana. when it hit HTTP:PUBLIC_IP:5601 I can see the kibana dashboard, but logs aren't there

Comment: Could you check your security group configuration on AWS: Maybe you can check with curl whether you can reach Kibana and Elasticsearch servers from your app servers. Your app servers need to reach Elasticsearch and Kibana apis over HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah, opened 22, 80, 5601, 9200. CURL is working fine as expected. And I tried http://PUBLIC_IP:5601/api/status getting the expected response. But still when I try "sudo filebeat setup", getting the above error. And unable to fetch in the data in elasticsearch too.

Comment: @hkulekci please review my yml once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe the filbeat is trying to communicate to kibana but unfortunately kibana is not running.

In filebeat.yml add this line

```
setup.ilm.overwrite: true
```

Ensure that elasticsearch and kibana is running then execute the setup command of filebeat. Keep posted, Thanks!!!

Comment: then how can I specify to create a custom index name in filebeat.yml?

Comment: In filebeat.yml mention you custom index name 

Example:

```
output.elasticsearch:
hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
index: "test1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The overwrite setting can be changed by passing -E flag for current command only that way:

$ `sudo filebeat setup --index-management -E setup.ilm.overwrite: true`

This will result in overwriting the index without changing the filebeat.yml, so the index remains read-only.